# Recursively querying a many-to-many relationship

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a family tree in Django and I can't figure out how to reference an object's children, and the children's children of the object's children, and so on. .

This is my model with the function I'm using to try to get the family tree:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    referrals = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False)

    def tree(self):
        refs = {}
        for ref in self.referrals.all():
            refs[ref] = ref.tree()

        return refs
```

This seems to work, however, if the children also has children, then it says the following:

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Ideally, I want the tree function to return a string object that is a nested list, so I can just place the result in the template, as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li>Member A</li>
    <li>Member B
        <ul>
            <li>Member BA</li>
             <li>Member BB</li>
        </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Member C</li>
</ul>
```

Would appreciate any suggestions, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you build the tree having one of the children pointing to one of the parents, you will create a cycle in your graph, causing your `tree` function to run infinitely.

Then, you have to avoid to add a `referral` that has parental relation somehow to the Member you're adding in it.

Also, I would recommend to name the reverse relation for clarity in your code:

```
# Add related name in order to access parents from a member
# like this:
# member.parents instead of members.referrals_set
referrals = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False, related_name='parents')
```